# drag and drop angular (conservar índices entre listas...)

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Queridos compañeros os agradecería muchísimo vuestro ayuda, estoy creando una app de nutrición. Le he instalado el módulo de  drag and drop (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) para poder desplazar los alimentos en diferentes ingestas (desayuno, comida, cena) el problema es que cuando desplazo los alimentos pierdo el índice de la matriz original, y los cálculos son erróneos ( y no puedo eliminarlos al perder el índice...). He subido mi código en este editor en línea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-material-pl94jv. ¿Os ocurre cómo poder desplazar los alimentos sin perder el índice y  los cálculos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema se debe a utilizar el indice del arreglo de los alimentos que se van almacenando, al cambiar, el peso siempre iba a cambiar, espero que esto ayude.

Elimine el arreglo general de alimentos y utilicé los arreglos de cada tiempo de comida para ajustar los pesos.

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem
} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';


export interface Alimento {
  nombre: string;
  tipo: string;
  peso_Int: number;
  prot: number;
  lip: number;
  hc: number;
  link_imagen: string;
  n_int_tarjeta: number;
  pesoAlimento: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  desayuno: Alimento[]
  comida: Alimento[]
  cena: Alimento[]

  datebasesAlimentos: {
    id: number;
    nombre: string;
    tipo: string;
    peso_Int: number;
    prot: number;
    lip: number;
    hc: number;
    n_int_tarjeta: number;
    link_imagen: string;
  }[] = [

    {
      id: 5,
      nombre: "arroz",
      tipo: "farinaceos",
      peso_Int: 20,
      prot: 1.4,
      lip: 0.2,
      hc: 15.2,
      n_int_tarjeta: 0,
      link_imagen: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QhuwtYlpqG6BoNfY5U88KtxbN1EaLAes",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      nombre: "patatas",
      tipo: "farinaceos",
      peso_Int: 100,
      prot: 2.2,
      lip: 0.2,
      hc: 15.2,
      n_int_tarjeta: 0,
      link_imagen: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1g_WD0OcH4YHKdSKkuUYNqk4H65A1TDv5",
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      nombre: "lentejas",
      tipo: "farinaceos",
      peso_Int: 30,
      prot: 7.3,
      lip: 0.4,
      hc: 14.6,
      n_int_tarjeta: 0,
      link_imagen: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1FYjZKs5EAl50NqXN25iOaCLHx-8okOTn",
    },

  ];

  nuevoAlimento: string = "";

  inputProt: number = 30;
  inputLip: number = 20;
  inputCarb: number = 75;

  //  FUNCIONES:

  constructor() {
    this.desayuno = []
    this.comida = []
    this.cena = []
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  calcularPeso(alimento, arrAlimentos) {
    return Math.round((alimento.peso_Int * 5) / arrAlimentos.length)
  }

  ajustarPeso(tiempoDeComida) {
    const todosLosAlimentos = [
      ...this.desayuno,
      ...this.comida,
      ...this.cena
    ]
    return tiempoDeComida.map(alimento => {
      alimento.pesoAlimento = this.calcularPeso(alimento, todosLosAlimentos)
      return alimento
    })
  }

  ajustarTodosLosPesos() {
    this.desayuno = this.ajustarPeso(this.desayuno)
    this.comida = this.ajustarPeso(this.comida)
    this.cena = this.ajustarPeso(this.cena)
  }

  agregarAlimento(): any {
    let index = this.datebasesAlimentos.findIndex(
      (item) => item.nombre == this.nuevoAlimento
    );

    this.desayuno.unshift({
      nombre: this.nuevoAlimento,
      tipo: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].tipo,
      peso_Int: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].peso_Int,
      prot: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].prot,
      lip: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].lip,
      hc: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].hc,
      link_imagen: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].link_imagen,
      n_int_tarjeta: this.datebasesAlimentos[index].n_int_tarjeta,
      pesoAlimento: 0,
    });

    this.ajustarTodosLosPesos()
    this.nuevoAlimento = "";
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop < string[] > ) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }

    this.desayuno = this.ajustarPeso(this.desayuno)
    this.comida = this.ajustarPeso(this.comida)
    this.cena = this.ajustarPeso(this.cena)
  }

  eliminar(tiempoDeComida, i) {
    tiempoDeComida.splice(i, 1);
    this.ajustarTodosLosPesos()
  }

  borrarTodo() {
    this.desayuno = [];
    this.comida = [];
    this.cena = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Ante todo gracias por tu tiempo, mi solución funciona bien siempre que todos los alimentos no se muevan de la lista desayuno a otra lista como la comida o la cena. He probado tu solución pero no funcionaría correctamente el cáculo del peso de alimento (en tu caso siempre da el mismo peso da igual cuantos alimentos haya...) y tampoco podría eliminar un elemento selectivamente.

Comment: Disculpa había entendido mal la lógica, actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa yo no explique bien la lógica en el anunciado, creo que ya casi esta...necesitaría que el cálculo fuese global es decir, si yo pongo 3 unidades de arroz en el  desayuno el cálculo saldría 33g por ración pero si por ejemplo pongo 1 unidad en cada ingesta necesitaría que diese el mismo cálculo, o sí pongo 2 raciones en la comida y 1 en la cena...la función eliminar da error. Gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo, un cordial saludo.

Comment: Claro entiendo, realice un ajuste específicamente para eso, es necesario tomar en cuenta todos los pesos ya introducidos por lo tanto hice un arreglo auxiliar construido a partir de todos los tiempos de comida.

Comment: Excelente aporte compañero, funciona correctamente, voy a estudiar bien la lógica que has propuesto. La función eliminar también funciona correctamente (olvidé modificar el HTML para llamar a la nueva función). Un cordial saludo, José.